# Object class throwing class cast Exception

Tags: java

In this Problem 
ItemEvent's method getIten() returns Object and the date is declared as int type.
but when I am equating object item after type-casting to Integer.

```
public  void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent  e)
 {
  Object item = e.getItem();
  if ((Integer)item==date) System.out.println("ok ");
   else System.out.println(" not ok");
  }
```

I am getting the Exception

```
   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at View.Alarm.itemStateChanged(Alarm.java:77)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: So getItem() returns a String.

Comment: it returns a Object

Comment: 'Object class' is not in evidence anywhere in this question other than your incorrect title.

Comment: Event getitem returns object and I have typecasted it to integer so there is the object in my code see property EJP

Comment: check this oracle link for the getItem() method EJP for your reference  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

That's because your e.getItem() returns String so you cannot cast it to Integer. Try doing:

```
if (Integer.parseInt((String)item)==date) System.out.println("ok ");
```

Comment: getItem method returns Object not String but the Thing is if i downcast it to int and compare to any int value why this Exception is there and by using          if (Integer.parseInt(item.toString())==date)  it is working now

Comment: @akhilsinghal A String is an Object. You need to review the basics.

Comment: i am not clear @Patrick   if i downcast this return object to int and then compare with int then why there is the exception including String there is only use to two things Integer class and object class my doubt is that this object internally is using toString method somewhere

Comment: `item` is a String and you cannot cast a String to an Integer. You can only convert String to int with parseInt.

Comment: When your getItem method returns an Object it doesn't mean it can be whatever you want. Object is just the parent class of every object so, having an Object object means that you have an object without knowing its type. In this case, your getItem returned an Object which is actually a String so you can't cast it to Integer, you have to use it as an String because that's what it is. Read about inheritance https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html and Object class https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Answer (score 0):

With the error you are getting, you would expect that the getItem() returns a String, even if the getItem returns an Object. Because String is an Object.

You may just use

```
if (Integer.valueOf(item.toString())==date) 
    System.out.println("ok ");
else 
    System.out.println(" not ok");
```